# How to run a beep every 3 seconds?

Tags: android

I trying to run a beep every 3 second on my code. 
I wrote this code .. but something is not working - and the beep appear only once and i get a crash

My application is runs with more UI feature so i need to do the beep on different thread.

The code:

```
private Timer _timeTimeToBeep;
private TimerTask _task;
private Thread _thread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    _displayValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayValue);

    displayValueUpdate();

    _timeTimeToBeep = new Timer();

    _task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


            _thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    playSound();
                }
            });

            _thread.start();
        }
    };

}


 public void playSound(){
    final ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);
    toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);
}

 // START BEEP BUTTON HERE
 public void startPlayClickBtn(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    _timeTimeToBeep.schedule(_task, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your startPlayClickBtn like below:

```
// START BEEP BUTTON HERE
 public void startPlayClickBtn(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    _timeTimeToBeep.schedule(_task, 3000, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are missing one parameter for the `schedule` method. You must pass `task, delay, period` to it.

Change it like this:

```
public void startPlayClickBtn(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    _timeTimeToBeep.schedule(_task, 3000, 3000);
}
```